# Populating ObservableCollection from XML file generically

Tags: c#, xml

In creating a method to generically add to an `ObservableCollection` from an `XML` file every record is the last one read.

I need to load multiple `XML` files into multiple `ObservableCollection`.  This is straight forward enough, but these `ObservableCollection` based off of multiple `Classes` and more will be added, not to mention that changes to the existing `Classes` would have to be reflected in the reading of `XML` file.  So I figured that having a method that would return a generic `ObservableCollection<object>` would solve this.  When the method is called the `Class` of the `ObservableCollection` would cast something like this;

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
GetXMLData(c);
```

Then in the Method for each XElement I would set each Property something like this;

```
public ObservableCollection<object> GetXMLData(object value)
{
    string fName = "MyPath";
    ObservableCollection<object> tableData = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    {
        XDocument fileXML = XDocument.Load(fs);
        var dataXML =
            from x in fileXML.Descendants("MyData")
            select x;
        foreach (XElement x in dataXML)
        {
            var data = (object)value;
            foreach (var prop in value.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = data.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(data, Convert.ChangeType(x.Attribute(prop.Name).Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
            }
            tableData.Add(data);
        }
    }
    return tableData;
}
```

This kind of works but it does have a problem.  Since I am casting data on value, **every record tableData is the last record read**.

Say XML data looks like this:

```
<Item Field1="Bob" Field2="10"  />
<Item Field1="Mike" Field2="20"  />
<Item Field1="Sam" Field2="30"  />
```

If you look at `ObservableCollection<object>` you see this:

```
Field1="Sam", Field2="30"
Field1="Sam", Field2="30"
Field1="Sam", Field2="30"
```

instead of seeing this:

```
Field1="Bob", Field2="10"
Field1="Mike" Field2="20"
Field1="Sam" Field2="30"
```

Notes:

1. I do have logic for error handling bad data that isn't there. So ignore that
2. You can safely assume that attributes of the XML file match perfectly for the Class

edit: tried to clarify my question.  Sorry wanted to show what I did not just "Hey how you do this?"

Comment: What *exactly* is your question? I don't see a specific question being asked here.

Comment: @GEEF Please look at the question, I just state the question more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...all of the instances of `data` in your loop are actually references to `value`. They're not "new" objects. So, what you're doing on each loop is changing the properties of `value`, which I'm sure is not what you want. If you `Debug.WriteLine(value)`, on each iteration, you'll see what I mean. So, all three `data` instances and `value` will always be the same. If you know what the type of `value` is, you should create *new* instances of that, set it's properties accordingly. Assuming you the type has a non-argument public constructor:

```
var data = Activator.CreateInstance( value.GetType() );
```

...would get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  I understood why it was happening but the key Activator.CreateInstance.  Everything I was trying around.GetType() was not working.